Sci-fi book set on a primitive alien planet where the non-human inhabitants are born in the ocean, then transition to land after maturing
I'm looking for a sci-fi book I read more than 30 years ago.
It takes place on a primitive alien planet where the non-human inhabitants are born in the ocean, then transition to land after maturing. The waters are getting turbulent and are injuring and/or killing the offspring. One male character is injured during transition and walks with a limp. He is bullied by the larger male characters. I don't remember any human characters in this book. I remember the males rutting to attract the females. I believe they may have used a tide pool for the young.

Reminds me of "The Narrow Land" by Jack Vance, but that's a novelette, not a book, and I don't remember if the protagonist walks with a limp. It was originally published in the July 1967 issue of Fantastic, which you can read for free in the Luminist Archive.

@DannyMcG I never read East of Eden but the ISFDB labels it "non-genre". How does it resemble the OP's description?

@user 14111 Drat! I meant West of Eden, (Harry Harrison) like I said it's been a long time since I read it

These don't feel right, but I do want to look closer at "The Narrow Land" as I haven't been able to find as much about it yet. But I'm pretty sure that it's not the story I'm looking for

@Shirley In the first comment I linked to a place where you can read "The Narrow Land".

@user14111 Thank you, I had noticed that link, but when I first tried to download it, it didn't work. I did download it today and read it. While it is a great read, it is not the story I'm looking for.
